# Object composition with constructors in Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

I have a Motor class for my individual stepper motors. Now I'm coding a Motor**s** class to synchronize the steppers movements, but I'm having problems to instantiate the Motor classes inside Motors.

I'm getting this error:

```
Robot:238:5: error: '((Motors*)this)->Motors::a' does not have class type
 a.enable(1); b.enable(1); c.enable(1);
```

So far this is my Motors class code:

```
class Motors{
public:
  Motor a(xstep, xdir, xenable, xend, true);
  Motor b(ystep, ydir, yenable, yend);
  Motor c(zstep, zdir, zenable, zend);

  Motors(){

  }

  void go_home(){
    a.enable(1); b.enable(1); c.enable(1);
    a.set_dir(0); b.set_dir(0); c.set_dir(0);
    delay(mtime) 
  }
};
```

Also tried instantiating inside the Motors constructor, but it doesn't work.

Comment: May be useful to post your question here: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is not Arduino specific, but a generic C++ problem

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `enable` and `set_dir` are methods on the Motor class. So you need three instances of Motor in the Motor class. If you are fine with the default constructor for each Motor object then you can encapsulate them like:

```
class Motors
{
  public:
    Motors() {
    }

    void go_home() {
      a.enable(1); b.enable(1); c.enable(1);
      a.set_dir(0); b.set_dir(0); c.set_dir(0);
      delay(mtime);
    }

  private:
    Motor a;
    Motor b;
    Motor c;
};
```

Comment: I'm passing parameters to the Motor class, so can't use the default constructor. Already found the correct code structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Motors{
public:
  Motor a = Motor(xstep, xdir, xenable, xend, amax, true);
  Motor b = Motor(ystep, ydir, yenable, yend, bmax);
  Motor c = Motor(zstep, zdir, zenable, zend, cmax);

  Motors(){

  }

  void go_home(){
    a.enable(1); b.enable(1); c.enable(1);
    a.set_dir(0); b.set_dir(0); c.set_dir(0);
    delay(mtime) 
  }
};
```

Comment: How do I close the question?